# Getting Stack Overflow Error when writing log by using log4j

Tags: java, selenium, log4j

I'm using log4j for writing log when running test automation.

Here is my method to write log:

```
public class Log {

private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName()); 

public static void info(String message)
{
    Log.info(message);
}

}
```

But whenever I use it, the stack overflow error is thrown like below:

Calling method:

```
Log.info("Click action is performed on My Account link");
```

Error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError at 
helpers.Log.info(Log.java:21) at 
helpers.Log.info(Log.java:21) at 
helpers.Log.info(Log.java:21) at 
helpers.Log.info(Log.java:21)
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hint: using the very same names all over the place for very different objects and classes is a really bad idea; as it can lead to such interesting problems as you are facing ... right now. Besides: please read about java coding style conventions. If you had called your `Logger` object `logger` for example (instead of calling it `Log` you would have avoided this problem as well). So: field/member names start with lowercase letters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont see the configuration for log4j.properties file. try this

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
public class Logs {

    public static Logger Application_Log = Logger.getLogger(Logs.class.getName());

    public Logs(){
         DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j-config.xml");
    }
public void info(String message){
        Application_Log.info(message);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @karthick23
I dont use log4j.properties file but using log4j.xml instead of. Below is my file:

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
 debug="false">
 <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
  <param name="File" value="logfile.log" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m %n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>
 <root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
 </root>
</log4j:configuration>

Comment: to use xml you should use DOMConfigurator. have updated the code

Comment: then it should be because recursive calls since your having logger and class name as same.. use different unique class name for your class and logger instance and go to project--clean. clean your project and run again

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your class' `info(String)` method, not the `Logger`'s `info(String)` method: your class is also called `Log`.

Use `Log.Log.info` instead - or rename your `Log` class, or rename your `Log` member variable.

This is one reason to follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: I tried to rename the Log member variable to log
`package helpers;   import org.apache.log4j.Logger;  
public class Log{  
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName());   public static void info(String message)  
{  
log.info(message);  
}  
}`
 But still getting issue. Can you please help? @Andy Turner